# What is the status of former Brazilian president Michel Temer prosecution for corruption charges?

Tags: president, corruption, law, brazil

[image: image0]

[Michel Temer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michel_Temer), former
Brazilian president who took office after the impeachment of Dilma
Rousseff in August 2016, has since been investigated on accusations of
corruption.

In 2017, Brazil’s top anti-corruption prosecutor charged Michel Temer
with obstruction of justice and racketeering[1]. Because he was a
sitting President, the question of whether a trial should be held was up
to Congress. At the end of 2017, lawmakers voted to spare Michel Temer
from standing trial, twice, with the New York Times titling in October
“President Temer of Brazil Dodges Corruption Prosecution, Again”[2].
This move was reportedly motivated by the fear of political turmoil and
the proximity of the following presidential elections, along with
arguments of “presidential immunity”. However, critics speculated that
the real reason was the fear among lawmakers such investigations could
implicate them directly.

After his mandate was over in the end of 2018, the prosecution resumed.
In March 2019, Michel Temer was arrested[3] on the basis of new
corruption charges, after which he was released under a “habeas corpus”
ruling. In May 2019, he was arrested again, released again 6 days later
under the same decision[4]. His release was conditioned by the
following restrictions:

- banned from contacting individuals under investigation;
- banned from changing addresses and leaving the country;
- hand over passports, and frozen bank accounts;
- banned from holding public office.

As of March 2019, there were 10 pending inquiries involving the former
president Michel Temer, according to DW journal[5]. I have made a
summary of allegations released by the press that I have collected so
far. For each allegation, the date, a news report, the prosecutor when
applicable, his sources and finally the amounted bribes. Quote marks
depict quotations from the news report:

- August 2016, alleged by jailed construction magnate Marcelo
  Odebrecht, “told prosecutors he contributed illegally to the
  election campaign of now-interim President Michel Temer in 2014”,
  reported by Reuters[6]. Investigations are still running. Amount
  of **$1.8m**.
- June 2017, alleged by Brazil’s chief prosecutor, Rodrigo Janot,
  accusing Michel Temer of “taking a $152,000 bribe from, an
  intermediary, (…) an act that ‘helped to compromise the image of the
  Federal Republic of Brazil.’”. reported by the New York Times[7],
  based on a secret tape recording[8]. Moreover, “a further $11
  million in bribes was promised, according to the charges, to
  Mr. Temer and Rodrigo Rocha Loures, a close aide to the president
  who was filmed taking delivery of a suitcase that the authorities
  say contained the payment.” Amount of **$152k**.
- September 2017, alleged by Brazil’s chief prosecutor, Rodrigo Janot,
  accusing Michel Temer of “taking bribes and of conspiring to buy the
  silence of a witness” and “acted as leader of a criminal
  organization”, reported by BBC News[1], based on “the plea-bargain
  testimony of the owners of the meatpacker JBS, Joesely Batista and
  Wesley Batista”. Amount of **$190m**.
- December 2018, alleged by Brazil’s prosecutor general, Raquel Dodge,
  accusing Michel Temer of “corruption and money laundering in
  connection to a graft investigation into the granting of port
  concessions in exchange for bribes”, reported by DW[9], “based on
  a report by the federal police, the charges allege that Temer
  changed laws to the benefit of some companies in the port sector in
  exchange for kickbacks (…) The charges allege Temer was paid through
  companies owned by friends.”. Amount of **$8.3m**.
- March 2019, alleged by Rio de Janerio prosecutors, accusing Michel
  Temer of having“received a R$1m bribe in exchange for awarding three
  companies a construction contract for [a] nuclear facility (…)
  prosecutors said Temer’s ‘criminal organization’ committed crimes
  including cartel formation, active and passive corruption, money
  laundering and fraudulent bidding processes”, reported by The
  Guardian[10]. Amount of **$200k**.

There is also a pending investigation extending from the Lava Jato
operation, involving almost a third of Michel Temer’s cabinet, which
supports the hypothesis of a systemic culture of corruption around
him[11].

English-written reports on the issue date back more than one year.
Perhaps Portuguese-speakers will be advantaged to answer my questions
here, and also those familiar with the Brazilian justice system:

- What is the legal support for the charges that were bypassed by
  Congress while he was in office not being reinstated the moment he
  left his seat?
- The latest reports on those investigations are more than one year
  old. Have there been any developments that have not been visible in
  the English-written press?
- Given Michel Temer alleged attempts to obstruction of justice,
  corruption of witnesses, sprawling links to Brazilian politics and
  depiction as a “kingmaker”, and the fact he has not been sentenced
  yet, do you think there is a reasonable risk that he will dodge any
  accountability?

---

1. 15 Sep 2017, https://www.bbc.com/news/world-latin-america-41275822
2. 25 Oct 2017,
   https://www.nytimes.com/2017/10/25/world/americas/brazil-michel-temer-corruption.html
3. 21 Mar 2019,
   https://www.theguardian.com/world/2019/mar/21/brazils-former-president-michel-temer-arrested-in-corruption-investigation
4. 15 May 2019,
   https://www1.folha.uol.com.br/internacional/en/brazil/2019/05/court-decides-unanimously-to-release-ex-president-michel-temer.shtml
5. 21 Mar 2019,
   https://www.dw.com/en/brazils-former-president-temer-arrested-on-corruption-charges/a-48009786
6. 06 Aug 2016,
   https://www.reuters.com/article/us-brazil-corruption/brazils-odebrecht-gave-illegal-funds-to-temer-campaign-report-idUSKCN10I01X
7. 26 Jun 2017,
   ​https://www.nytimes.com/2017/06/26/world/americas/brazil-temer-corruption-charge-joesley-batista.html
8. 17 May 2017,
   https://www.nytimes.com/2017/05/17/world/americas/brazil-michel-temer-joesley-batista-corruption.html
9. 19 Dec 2018,
   https://www.dw.com/en/brazilian-prosecutor-files-graft-charges-against-outgoing-president-michel-temer/a-46811368
10. 21 Mar 2019,
    https://www.theguardian.com/world/2019/mar/21/brazils-former-president-michel-temer-arrested-in-corruption-investigation
11. 12 Apr 2017, https://www.bbc.com/news/world-latin-america-39574355

Comment: Caveat: I know nothing at all about Temer or Brazilian politics. That being said, if he hasn't been tried and convicted, or even charged, why would he "go to jail"?

Comment: @CGCampbell There is [audio evidence of bribery](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2017/may/18/brazil-explosive-recordings-implicate-president-michel-temer-in-bribery).

Comment: Can you refocus this question to be more about a specific political issue? This site generally isn't a good place to follow breaking news or ongoing events, and speculation about the future is one of the main close reasons.

Comment: @divibisan I understand. I am drafting a more elaborated version with as focused question.

Comment: @CGCampbell I've updated the post with material supporting the general idea that, given the number of cases in which he is involved, it is difficult to doubt Michel Temer acts of corruption. Although there is still a very narrow statistical chance that he is the victim of a massive plot.

Comment: @divibisan I've updated the post, I hope that fits better the general guidelines of this community.

Answer (score 4):

As of February 2022, Temer has been acquitted of the main charges against him, and the others show signs that will follow the same fate. Going charge by charge (all sources in Portuguese):

1. The "Marcelo Odebrecht" case: Odebrecht's allegations were dismissed by electoral justice on [non ultra petita](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non_ultra_petita) grounds ([source](https://www.conjur.com.br/2017-jun-09/tse-desconsidera-delacoes-odebrecht-mantem-temer-cargo)). In the criminal justice, the case was transferred from the Supreme Court to the Federal Court ([source](https://oglobo.globo.com/politica/politicos-com-inqueritos-da-lava-jato-transferidos-para-justica-estadual-24169603)).
2. The "secret tape" case: acquitted due to lack of evidence ([source](https://www.conjur.com.br/2019-out-16/juiz-chama-denuncia-temer-ilacao-absolve-sumariamente)). The judge considered the tape was tampered by the prosecution. In a separate suit, Joesley Batista, the businessman who recorded the conversation, was ordered to pay
   R$ 300k as damages to Temer ([source](https://www.conjur.com.br/2020-nov-25/stj-confirma-condenacao-joesley-indenizar-temer-entrevista)).
3. The "leader of criminal organization" case: acquitted due to lack of evidence ([source](https://www.migalhas.com.br/quentes/345083/juiz-absolve-temer-e-outros-acusados-do-quadrilhao-do-mdb)). Update: acquittal confirmed on appeal ([source](https://www.cartacapital.com.br/politica/trf-1-mantem-absolvicao-de-temer-cunha-e-outros-por-quadrilhao-do-mdb/)).
4. The "ports” case: acquitted due to lack of evidence ([source](https://g1.globo.com/jornal-nacional/noticia/2021/03/19/justica-absolve-temer-da-acusacao-de-favorecer-empresas-do-setor-portuario.ghtml)).
5. The "nuclear facility" case: acquitted due to lack of evidence ([source](https://blogs.oglobo.globo.com/lauro-jardim/post/justica-federal-rejeita-nova-denuncia-em-caso-que-levou-temer-e-moreira-franco-prisao.html)).

Apparently, there are other ongoing investigations against him, but as the most bombastic accusations were dismissed, it is highly unlikely that he will be considered guilty in any crime. Also, because he is not a president anymore, all the suits against him had to be transferred to local courts from the Supreme Court. All this "paper movement" plays in favor of the accused since Brazilian justice is subject to [statute of limitations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statute_of_limitations).

As for your other questions:

> What is the legal support for the charges that were bypassed by Congress while he was in office not being reinstated the moment he left his seat?

They were reinstated. You said that yourself:

> After his mandate was over in the end of 2018, the prosecution resumed...

> The latest reports on those investigations are more than one year old.
> Have there been any developments that have not been visible in the
> English-written press?

Yes, check the sources in this answer. They are all in Portuguese though.

> Given Michel Temer alleged attempts to obstruction of justice,
> corruption of witnesses, sprawling links to Brazilian politics and
> depiction as a “kingmaker”, and the fact he has not been sentenced
> yet, do you think there is a reasonable risk that he will dodge any
> accountability?

A big yes to this. Just want to add that all the accusations did not resist challenges in court, so while some will see that as Temer dogging accountability, others will see that as justice against an innocent man being made.